Playwright/Browserbase executing click but still waiting for element
I am trying to run a script using Playwright with Browserbase. In this I execute a click event on an element (a cookie accept button) with a CSS selector as follows:
await this.page.locator(selector).first().click({ force: true });
The element is successfully located, but the click event then times out as it says that it is waiting for the element to be visible.
However, when I watch the session replay, I can see that a) the element is visible and b) it appears to be successfully clicked. Yet Playwright still says it is waiting for it to be visible.
Before click screenshot from replay:

After click screenshot from replay:

Here is the error being thrown:
[TimeoutError3: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
Call log:
  - waiting for locator('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')
    - locator resolved to <button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler">Accept & close</button>
  - attempting click action
    2 × waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
      - element is not visible
    - retrying click action
    - waiting 20ms
    2 × waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
      - element is not visible
    - retrying click action
      - waiting 100ms
    44 × waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
       - element is not visible
     - retrying click action
       - waiting 500ms
]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?
Edit:
I also tried with the following code and ran into the same issue:
  await this.page.locator(selector).waitFor({
    state: "visible",
  });
  await this.page.locator(selector).first().click();


This code worked for me await page.goto("https://www.spareroom.co.uk/");   await page     .locator("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")     .first()     .click({ force: true });

This turned out to be just a bug in the class where I was implementing the method. I was using a facade pattern to wrap around multiple browser libraries and the value of this.page was being unintentionally silently altered, leading  to this bug down the line.
